# CMake - Link project with C runtime object files in correct order

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, abi

There are C runtime / startup files: `crt0.o`, `crti.o`, `crtbegin.o` … `crtend.o`, `crtn.o`.

- `crtbegin.o` and `crtend.o` are provided by the toolchain (GCC)
- `crt0.o`, `crti.o` and `crtn.o` are implemented by myself in my
  project scope.

The project is about running the executable on i686 bare metal so without the OS.

**The problem is witin the linking of the final executable - The order in which the project object files are linked with all the C runtime files above matters.**

My build system is CMake where I use `target_sources` command to define the source files used (compiled and then linked together) for the executable:

```
set( BARE_METAL app.bin )
add_executable( ${BARE_METAL} "" )

target_sources( ${BARE_METAL}
  PRIVATE
    boot.s  # contains symbols analogical to crt0.s
    crti.s
    crtn.s
    a.cpp
    b.cpp
    # … other files go here
)
target_link_options( ${BARE_METAL}
  PUBLIC
    -t linker.ld
    -nostdlib
    -nostartfiles
)
target_link_libraries( ${BARE_METAL}
  PUBLIC
    support
)
```

The problem is GCC is not linking with `crtbegin.o` and `crtend.o` even though it can be found in my toolchain:

- `toolchain/i686-elf/lib/gcc/i686-elf/10.0.1/crtbegin.o`
- `toolchain/i686-elf/lib/gcc/i686-elf/10.0.1/crtend.o`

Could you please advise me how to invoke the linker with all the required arguments in correct order from CMake? I would expect a link command analogical to

```
./i686-elf-ld -t linker.ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles boot.o crti.o crtbegin.o a.o b.o -libsupport.a crtend.o crtn.o
```

*Please notice the order of C runtime files. I have simplified the direktory structures of all the files but the crucial point should be cought here.*

Many thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me… Martin

**UPDATE:**

I tried to investigate more in parallel waiting for any kind of advise here and the promising way seems to be using `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` to define project specific build rule for linking.

My project uses toolchain file which is being set before the root/main project() statement. Within the subproject I set the `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` and it seems to work having no consequence on other subprojects. That's why I call it promissing although the whole thing does not work yet.

My plan is to create an object library out of the three project specific C runtime files `crt0.o`, `crti.o` and `crtn.o` to remove them from `<OBJECTS>`, make the project depend on this object library but manage the runtime files manually within the link build rule.

**Do you think this way would successfully end?** I will post the results once I have some...

Comment: have you tried `target_link_libraries()` with the object files you expect to link with?

Comment: @vsh no, let me try. But what I already tried is to list them I target_sources. It does not work. The problem is crtbegin.o and crtend.o go somehow in the middle of other project object files... so to manage the order is the trouble I have...

Comment: in a build dir you can search for link.txt which cmake generates and there is the exact link command line. `target_sources` wouldn't accept object files, but `target_link_libraries` would if you put filenames with extension there

Comment: Yes, you could modify `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` for your project and add `crtbegin.o` in front and `crtend.o` after and add `-nostdlib -nostartfiles` actually too. But for compiling C++ you have to have much more...

Comment: @KamilCuk My intension is just to construct a link command, the compilation remains untouched, doesn't it? Could you please share more details?

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER>  -t linker.ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles boot.o crti.o crtbegin.o <FLAGS> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS>
> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>  -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES> crtend.o crtn.o")` ;) Or maybe remove the `-t linker.ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles` depending how you want to structure it.

Comment: @KamilCuk That looks fine. What I am trying to work on is how to build `crt0.o`, `crti.o` and `crtn.o` which are being part of my project sources and thus part of `<OBJECTS>`. I try to separate them to an object library, which effectively remove them from `<OBJECTS>` but are not built unless I add the object library to `target_link_libraries` but then its all added to <OBJECTS> once again :( So any other idea?

Comment: That is hard, because they should be available before you link anything. I could see: remove them from `target_sources(${BARE_METAL}` and add another like `add_library(BARE_METAL_CRTS crt0.s crti.s crtn.s)` and do `add_dependencies(${BARE_METAL} BARE_METAL_CRTS)`.  Or I would go with creating a separate cmake project just to compile everything needed to compile this project. Or you could do it by hand with `add_custom_target`+`add_custom_command` pair and also do `add_dependencies`, which doesn't actually sounds that bad.

Comment: @KamilCuk Adding `BARE_METAL_CRTS` as dependency to `BARE_METAL` implies the object files to be built. A step forward done :)  Now I need to add the object files to the `CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE` including the location deep within the build folder of the `BARE_METAL_CRTS` target...

Comment: @KamilCuk I have implemented the working solution which can be found in my question answer down below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @KamilCuk I have successfully made it running. Here is the solution I made (to be used by anyone trying to solve the same issue)

```
project( Bare_Metal LANGUAGES CXX C ASM )

set( BARE_METAL app.bin )
set( BARE_METAL_CRTS app-crts )

add_library( ${BARE_METAL_CRTS} OBJECT
    boot.s  # contains symbols analogical to crt0.s
    crti.s
    crtn.s
)

add_executable( ${BARE_METAL} "" )

target_sources( ${BARE_METAL}
  PRIVATE
    a.cpp
    b.cpp
    # … other files go here
)
target_link_options( ${BARE_METAL}
  PUBLIC
    -t linker.ld
    -nostdlib
    -nostartfiles
)
target_link_libraries( ${BARE_METAL}
  PUBLIC
    support
)

# This ensures the boot.o crti.o, crtn.o to be build prior to BARE_METAL target
add_dependencies( ${BARE_METAL} ${BARE_METAL_CRTS} )

# Ask GCC to get the full path name of crtbegin. and crtend.o
execute_process( COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -print-file-name=crtbegin.o OUTPUT_VARIABLE CRTBEGIN_O OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE )
execute_process( COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -print-file-name=crtend.o OUTPUT_VARIABLE CRTEND_O OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

# Set linker executable to be used - navigate to the toolchain used (might be setup in toolchain file)
set( BARE_METAL_LINKER ${BARE_METAL_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/bin/${CMAKE_TARGET_PROCESSOR}-elf-ld )

set( CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "${BARE_METAL_LINKER} <CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS> <FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> boot.obj crti.obj ${REVOLTA_CRTBEGIN} <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES> ${REVOLTA_CRTEND} crtn.obj" )
```

Please keep in mind the code above is not copy-and-paste solution but is complete, working to be used as guide/inspiration to do such stuff :)